# Создание блока бонусов с фоном из псевдоэлементов

Tags: html5, вёрстка, background

Посоветуйте пожалуйста, как правильнее всего сверстать такой [image: вид блока]

блок с бонусами для адаптивных форматов ? Это изображение будет кнопкой.(их будет 3 на страницу расположенных по горизонтали) Меня больше всего смущает полупрозрачный шрифт который будет находится в зависимости от текста (пример 500грн, 20$, 5000р ...) и этот шрифт должен быть на весь блок при уменшении экрана браузера.

```css
.btn_top {
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px auto 0;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 284px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 0;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  background: transparent no-repeat 50% 50%;
}

.btn_top img {
  display: inline-block;
}

.btn_top span {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 45px;
}

.btn_top:hover,
.btn_top:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.btn_top__cart2:before {
  content: "бонус 500";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: 1;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 5;
}

.btn_top__cart2 {
  box-shadow: 0 -8px 30px rgba(164, 221, 48, 0.35), 0 34px 48px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.33);
  background-color: #54b228;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <button class="btn_top btn_top__cart2" type="button" data-href="">
                            <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/3HjKE.png" alt="foto2">
                            <span>БЕЗДЕПОЗИТНЫЙ</span><span> БОНУС 500 ГРН</span>
                        </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Подскажите, как добиться такого результата? Вариант, сделать это всё png картинкой не рассматривается.